# ajax autosuggest

Tags: asp.net

i can use auto-suggest with the text box `txtCode` like this...

```
as_jsonReportingTo = new bsn.AutoSuggest('<%= txtCode.ClientID %>', optionsRe);
```

Now I will create text boxes dynamically, i want to bind autosuggest with the new created text boxes. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

just give those dynamically generated controls a class. then do sth like (with a bit jQuery flavor)

```
var $controls = $('.mySpecialClass');
$controls.each(function (index, element) {
    var control = new bsn.AutoSuggest(element.id, optionsRe);
});
```